# What's the best way to get result from ReadAsStringAsync response?

Tags: c#, json, https, blazor, .net-8.0

**What I have**

This code calling my API:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.GetAsync("https://localhost:7094/api/MyResource/94d0e5ca-2be7-42f7-94dc-13955c11595c");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine($"RESPONSE: {responseBody}");

var payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(responseBody);
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);

Console.WriteLine($"PAYLOAD: {json}");
```

This code is called from `OnInitializedAsync` in a NET8 Blazor WASM client.

**The response I get**

The first WriteLine of the responseBody returns this:

```
{
    "creationOptions": 0,
    "id": 226,
    "isCanceled": false,
    "isCompleted": true,
    "isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
    "isFaulted": false,
    "result": {
        "content": {
            <Actual content>
        },
        "links": {
            <my hateoas links>
        }
    },
    "status": 5
}
```

That is correct.

**What's failing**

The deserialize of MyClass does not seem to happen correctly, because the second writeline returns this:

```
PAYLOAD: null
```

That's not unsurprising because the responseBody has added the http get results. I need to go down the json tree once.

I can't do:

```
var payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(responseBody.result);
```

Because responseBody is of type string, as you can see above.

**I have also tried**

to use

```
var payload = Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Payload<MyClass>>("https://localhost:7094/api/MyResource/94d0e5ca-2be7-42f7-94dc-13955c11595c");
```

But that returns:

```
{ "content": null, "links": null }
```

I suspect that's a timing issue (data is not ready yet when I writeline).

**What's the best way to get my actual payload from the json responseBody?**

**Fix after applying answer**

- I changed the API response type from Task to just IActionResult
- I removed the complexity of the payload wrapper. That was not necessary.

After that I could just do:

```
var myEntities = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<FabricageSoort>>("https://localhost:7094/api/FabricageSoort/");
```

Comment: You don't show what `MyClass` is. And how is `FabricageScoort` related to this class?

Comment: Why not just create a class for the json-root-object and deserialize that type instead of the nested one?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain That's a bad edit ;)

Comment: @Spikee what is `MyClass` and `Payload`? Can you please provide a full [mre] (for example @github)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full answer but:

> The first `WriteLine` of the `responseBody` returns this:

It seems that you need to fix your `https://localhost:7094/api/MyResource/94d0e5ca-2be7-42f7-94dc-13955c11595c` endpoint first. It seems that for some reason you are returning/serializing `Task<TResult>` instead of `TResult` which leads to the corresponding output. There are multiple possible reasons for that, like missing `await` in the code, or incorrect value used for serialization (the code for endpoint is needed for more precise advice).

> returns this: `PAYLOAD: null`
> That's not unsurprising because the responseBody has added the http get results.

That is actually surprising, since the response contains a JSON object, an non-null instance of `MyClass` should be deserialized to a non-nullable instance, though it properties obviously would not be correctly filled.

Also if you are not actually serializing `System.Task<TResult>` instance then you can always create a container and use it for deserialization. Something along these lines:

```
public ResponseResult<T>
{
   [JsonPropertyName("result")]
   public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

```
MyClass payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseResult<MyClass>>(responseBody).Result;
```

Comment: This got me going. I have simplified Task<ActionResult> to IActionResult. I have also removed the complexity of the payload class.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
{
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.GetAsync("API");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"RESPONSE: {responseBody}");
var fullResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(responseBody);

var payload = fullResponse?.result?.content;

if (payload != null)
{
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);
    Console.WriteLine($"PAYLOAD: {json}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Payload is null or not found in the response structure.");
}
}
```

Comment: "`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(responseBody);`"  is exactly what OP already does.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**